# Ransack with match exact word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I'm using ransack for search product like this :

```
Product.display_status.order('status asc').ransack(params[:q])
```

with combine predicates `name_or_meta_tag_cont`.

The problem is, that it selects more than i would like.

For example :

I would like to select product with keyword "foo bar", but my query select product with meta tag "foo barfoo, foo, bar" as well. To be clear, if i wanted to select product with meta tag "best product, bla, bla", I don't want the query to select "best products, bla, bla".

If I'm not use ransack :

```
Product.where("meta_tag ~* ? or name ~* ?", ' foo bar\\M', ' foo bar\\M')
```

Does anybody know how can I use that with ransack?

Comment: How exactly are you selecting tags, using search input or you have some predefined list of tags that you just click to include in search. Picture of your search from would be very helpful :)

Comment: @yoodaa I'm using single search input text, just type of some keywords of `name` or `meta_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

So you only want products that have "foo bar" as the exact name or meta tag?

`name_or_meta_tag_eq`

Comment: I want get products that have  "foo bar foo", not "foo bars foo" if I'm use keyword "foo bar"